# React component as classic object

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to have User object which would be react component so it can for example render it's profile. But I'd also like to access it's state, form other components when needed. I want to define some methods which would work as getter. So I'd like to do something like

```js
const User = module.exports = React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
                GoogleUser: React.PropTypes.object
        },
        getInitialState(){
                return {
                        name: 'John Doe',
                        email: 'john@mail.com',
                        id: 123
                };
        },
        render(){
                return '<span>'+this.state.name+'</span>';
        },

        Profile(){
                return {
                    name: this.state.name,
                    email: this.state.email
                };
        }
});
```

But when I pass created element as an argument and access the `Profile()` method it is undefined. How can i do this in a manner that accessing the user would be direct and as little coding as possible?

Comment: Is this the exact code of your React component? It looks like a mix of ES6 `class` syntax (the method declarations) and ES5 syntax (`React.createClass({...})`).

Comment: Not exact, but all constructions are same. I use in my code stuff like render(){} and it works. But i was surprised too when i found out I can do that :D

Comment: I'm still getting my head around all the new ES6 syntax! Lots of surprises.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can accomplish this. The most idiomatic is to pass a change listener to your component that will be notified whenever the component state changes.

The basic idea is that you pass a callback prop to your component and update that callback whenever the state changes. So you would have something like

```js
    propTypes: {
        //parent component will declare and pass this observer
        onStateChange: React.PropTypes.func
    },

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            //declare default null function
            onStateChange: () => null,
        };
    },

    //call this function whenever a change is made to the state
    handleStateChange(newState) {
        onStateChange(newState);
    }
```

Another way of accomplishing this is to expose a function and access it using refs. See [Expose Component Functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html) in the React docs. This way is closer to the code you pasted above, but it is less commonly used and is a bit of a departure from the React paradigm. My suggestion is to really try and make the callback method work with your application architecture and only if you're sure it's not the right solution to go with the expose component functions approach.